# couldn't create array in class with constant size

Tags: arrays, class, constants

GCC compiler error when trying to create an array in a class with constant size. If do the same in the main function it's ok.

```
const int n[] = { 4, 18 };
class C{
    int a[n[0]];//error: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token
};

int main() {
    int b[n[0]];//it's ok here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change

```
const int n[] = { 4, 18 };
```

to

```
constexpr int n[] = { 4, 18 };
```

it works (just tested with gcc 7.4.0). The array is declared to be evaluated at compile time, which is needed to create the array with constant size.